# Invariance under derived equivalence of a Gorenstein projective bimodule

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

A module $M$ over an finite dimensional algebra $A$ is called Gorenstein projective in case there exists an exact complex $(P_i)$ of projective $A$-modules such that the complex stays exact after applying the functor $Hom_A(-,A)$ and $M$ is isomorphic to a kernel of some map in the complex $(P_i)$.
Equivalently $M$ is Gorenstein projective in case $Ext_A^i(M,A)=0=Ext_A^i(Tr(M),A)$ when $M$ is the Auslander-Bridger transpose of $M$.

> Question: In case two algebras $A$ and $B$ are derived equivalent and $A$ as an $A$-bimodule is Gorenstein projective, is also $B$ as a $B$-bimodule Gorenstein projective?